# Extracting site title from URL

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to find a away to extract a site title from a URL entered into a field in PHP. For example, if the user were to enter the URL http://www.nytimes.com/2009/11/05/sports/baseball/05series.html, I would want "New York Times" or "NY Times" or something along those lines.

I know it's fairly easy to extract the title of the WINDOW... for example, the URL I linked would have the title "Yankees 7, Phillies 3 - Back on Top....", but this is exactly what I don't want.

For clarification, this is for adding sources to a quote. I want to be able to add a source to  quotes without a huge page URL and not just a link that says "Source".

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: if this is for citation, you should use the URI, because the URI is factually the source, regardless how long. [That's why `<blockquote>` and `<q>` offer a cite attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.2.2)

Comment: Agree with Gordon, if you're citing the page in any official manner, you need the whole URI.  Verifying a story given just 'New York Times' could be very difficult.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$source = parse_url('http://www.nytimes.com/....', PHP_URL_HOST); // www.nytimes.com
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no such thing as a "site title" , you can get

- the domain name (and then the owner name)
- the page's title
- I see you have the meta tag "cre" with the value "The New York Times" but you won't find it everywhere

You can do one thing : extract the domain name from the URL, and then get the first page's title

"http://www.nytimes.com/" will give you "The New York Times - Breaking News, World News & Multimedia"

Answer (score 3):

Build a list of URL prefixes to site names, and check for each prefix in turn from longest to shortest.

Comment: I could do that but that wouldn't be very flexible unless I had a massive list.

Comment: You could default to the page or site title if no entry is found.

Answer (score 3):

You'd surely need a lookup table mapping domains (nytimes.com) to your titles "NY Times" in which case it would be easy to do.

If you want to have a method that will work on any link from any domain, then it is a bit harder as PHP in itself is not going to be able to work out what is a uniform title as it will vary from site to site.

You can explode the URL easily enough, but how then would you be able to dissect nytimes into "NY" and "TIMES".

You may be able to find a web service that allows you to feed in a domain and get back a site title, but I do not know of one.

You are best off simply quoting the domain, trimmed like "NYTIMES.COM" as the source, or "NYTIMES".

Answer (score 3):

You would want to use `file_get_contents()` then run a match to check the text between any `<title></title>` tags - that then would be your title that you display.

Using `parse_url` wouldn't return the actual page title.

Something like:

```
<?php
$x = file_get_contents("http://google.com");
preg_match("/<title>(.+?)<\/title>/", $x, $match);
echo $match[1];
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). Here is an example:

```
require "simple_html_dom.php";

$url = "http://www.google.com";

$html = file_get_html( $url );

list( $title ) = $html->find( 'title' );

echo strip_tags( $title ); // Output: "Google"
```

Comment: thats not QUITE what I'm looking for... for the URL I linked, it gives the long page title that I do not want.